# Portfolio Page User story 7. The navbar should contain at least one link that I can click on to navigate to different sections of the page

Tags: html, css

Unable to navigate to different sections of my portfolio page by clicking my navigation links. sometimes even met with error 502 when i click on them.

I've tried to diagnose the problem by checking the reference ids of the href attributes in the a tags and check that the section tags are of parent element but to no avail.

```
<div id="nav-welcome">
    <div id="nav-box">
        <nav id="navbar">
              <a href id="#welcome-section">Home</a>
              <a href id="#projects">Projects</a>
              <a href id="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="welcome-section">
    <h1>Hello I am Gerwyn.</h1>
    <p>A Student invested in Web Development!</p>
</section>
```

I expect to be navigated to the section with the id="welcome-section" when i click on the link with the id "#welcome-section"

Comment: try this `<a href = "#welcome-section">Home</a>`

Answer (score 1):

the anchor tags (`a` element) needs an `href` attribute to set where to go when clicked. But you set the destination in `id` by mistake!. You should modify your `a` elements as: `<a href="#welcome-section">`

Try this way:

```css
#navbar a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 2px #590199 solid;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.spacer {height:300px; margin-top: 30px;}
```

```html
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="nav-welcome">
 <div id="nav-box">
 <nav id="navbar">
   <a href="#welcome-section">Home</a>
  <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
 </nav>
 </div>
 </div>

<div class="spacer">some content ...</div>

 <section id="welcome-section">
   <h1>Hello I am Gerwyn.</h1>
   <p>A Student invested in Web Development!</p>
 </section>

<div class="spacer">some content ...</div>

 <section id="projects">
   <h1>My Projects...</h1>
 </section>

<div class="spacer">some content ...</div>

 <section id="contact">
   <h1>My Contact...</h1>
 </section>
```

Comment: yes i have corrected them but the navigation still are not working as intended. could you take the time to take a look at my codepen: https://codepen.io/Gerwyn/pen/axXpvp        edit: if you click on the links on top, it won't take you to the different sections of the page

Comment: @TheUndertaker please see the edited answer to ensure it works this way. I checked your codepen, it has many wrongly styled elements (bad css positioning), eg: mixing several position:absolute/fixed with flex and etc... its layout is not designed well. if you remove your css, you see that it works

Comment: i tested out again myself and it looks like position:absolute is totally fine but just  by absolute positioning the child elements themselves inside a div or section. also fixed position for the nav is totally fine apparently. Take a look: https://codepen.io/Gerwyn/pen/JVzqgY                                                                     The only thing I'm trying to figure out now is that why are there small gaps for my width and height on the outside even though i put 100% width and height for my container... i wonder if you know the answer? :)

Comment: nvm it looks like i applied absolute position left/right/top/bottom:0 to a container holding everything. and it worked perfectly. take a look at my codepen if u'd like to see if i got anything wrong!         https://codepen.io/Gerwyn/pen/JVzqgY

Comment: @TheUndertaker can you explain what gap are you talking about exactly? i see you have set some margin and it could produce some free space...

Comment: you can see my codepen. if you remove this code:                                                   ```                                                                                                                                   #container {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}                                                                                                                                 ```                                             there will be gaps surrounding my page :)

Answer (score 0):

{

Use this you put the id between the "href" and link

Home

```
    <a href="#projects">Projects</a>

    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).